# Get language-dependent City and Country Name by Address or Lat/Long

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, location, google-geocoder

I basically want to retrieve the language-dependent name of a city and country, based on either the address (postal code, country name, country code) or the location (latitude, longitude).

Here's my use-case to make it more clearly:

- User A in Germany stores an item in a cloud database with his location and address (postal code, city, country name, country code). Because he lives in Germany, his address would probably be in German, e.g. [*50667 Köln, Deutschland*](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=50667%20K%C3%B6ln,%20Deutschland,%20DE&sensor=true&language=DE)
- User B in the USA retrieves the item from User A, but he cannot read the address because it's German. So he needs the English address, e.g. [*50667 Cologne, Germany*](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=50667%20K%C3%B6ln,%20Deutschland,%20DE&sensor=true&language=EN)
- User C in France also retrieves the item from User A, but he needs the address in French, e.g. [*50667 Cologne, Allemagne*](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=50667%20K%C3%B6ln,%20Deutschland,%20DE&sensor=true&language=FR)

On Android, I can use the Geocoding API to get the address translated in another language. There are two options: [getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) and   [getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int)). So I can either use the location with latitude/longitude or the address which is in the wrong language. Basically, my questions is, what is the better or faster way?

Another option would be to use the [Google Geocoding Web API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), but in this case, I would be limited to maximum queries per day.

I am also open to other ideas on how to get the address in another language.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an Android application, then go to the Geocoding API for Android. Although the Geocoding API for Web services is easy to build, like you said it has a limit.

For standard API, you will have:

- 2,500 free requests per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
- 50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

And if you enable the billing, you will need to pay $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 daily.

> Also, just take note this two approaches to Geocoding.
>
> Client-side geocoding, which is executed in the browser, generally in
>   response to user action. The Google Maps JavaScript API provides
>   classes that make the requests for you. This approach is described in
>   the [Google Maps JavaScript API
>   documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).
>
> HTTP server-side geocoding, which allows your server to directly query
>   Google's servers for geocodes. The Google Maps Geocoding API is the
>   web service that provides this functionality. Typically, you integrate
>   this service with other code that is running server-side. Server-side
>   geocoding is described in the [Google Maps Geocoding API
>   documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start).

Comment: What is the better/faster way on Android: getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults) orgetFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults)?

Comment: I think any of the two ways is ok. but if you consider the language, I will go to the cordinates(lat & lng) because this coordinates never change.